# Battlefield 3 Premium Edition says my code was used

Tags: battlefield-3

I bought battle field 3 premium about 2-3 years ago. I typed in the code and it says it was already used and I never used it, nor did I buy a used code.

Any help on how to fix this?

Comment: You'll have to contact EA.  Good luck with that, though, as the user has probably used it for a couple years at this point.

Comment: Not to sound like a dick or anything, but there is literally nothing we can do. If the code was used, then it was used. End of the story. You can try to contact EA and see what they can do about it, but it's entirely up to them. From a purely speculative point, I would wager that they aren't going to do anything about it.

Comment: You bought it 2-3 years ago and only tried using it now?

Comment: You should of used it when you got the game.